# No WiFi adapter found, Dell XPS 9570, Killer 1350 card

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell

Linux newbie here. I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 alongside Windows 10 on my machine. Everything was working smoothly for about a week and then, all of a sudden, the network card just decided to die on me. After installing firmware, and rebooting network manager, the card was still not accessible through BIOS, through Windows or Ubuntu. I couldn't even see it.

So I got a new card from dell (as the laptop is still under warranty), but they only have the same card to replace it with. Now, I have Bluetooth and the card works when I boot into windows. However, under WiFi, it still says there is no WiFi adapter.

Can someone please help?

Some further info:

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s20f0u5
   serial: 56:37:21:ac:5b:58
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device  link=yes multicast=yes
```

`rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep ath10k`:

```
(gives me nothing)
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a broken kernel update, try

`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Reboot

Comment: My god i can't believe that worked! Hours and rabbit holes of terminal inputs with no result. I suppose if nothing else i'm much more familiar with the terminal and how drivers etc actually work. Thanks a million for your fix!

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem as Dimitri. However, this fix only partially helped: before applying it I was not even able to use tethering via usb, now I can; but still no wi-fi adapter. What else can be done? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand how this fixed it for windows as well.  My machine has done the same thing, and even the bios self test shows no adapter connected.  How could the linux kernel effect that when it isn't even running.

Comment: amazing. this seems to have worked for me too. this has been broken for ages. didn't to reboot either. hope that doesn't mean that it's not actually fixed :O.

Comment: Great fix.. amazing one liner! Thank you!