# Wifi adapter not found, But bluetooth is found & working (Dell XPS 9570 - Killer 1650 - Ubuntu 19.10 - kernel 5.3.0.23)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, 19.10

I've got a lot of similarities as the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092682/no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-xps-9570-killer-1350-card). But it did not resolve my case. I am still a noob with Linux so bear with me.

TL;TR of other post: My WiFi adapter is not recognized by the OS. But the Bluetooth adapter is. (It must be the same hardware)

**Situation:**

- Dell XPS 9570 with Killer AX1650 WiFi/Bluetooth adapter.
- Dual boot system with Ubuntu 19.10 - Kernel 5.3.0.23 (Windows 10 everything works fine)
- Bluetooth works on Ubuntu (Even tethering via Bluetooth -> phone)
- Wired connection works fine (Via USB-c hub)
- Bluetooth headset works fine
- No WiFi device

**Logs:**

> rfkill list

results in:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So it shows no WiFi adapter.

> sudo lshw -C network

[results in](https://justpaste.it/7ak9a)

> dmesg | grep ath10k

[results in](https://justpaste.it/5d72k)

> lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

[results in](https://justpaste.it/3ku7f)

Already tried https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/ But it did not work for me.